# How to send inherited Object with JSON in Spring Controller?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, inheritance

I work with Hibernate and everything is fine except this case. If I have class and inherited classes , when I send Object like that with JSON in Spring Controller , always I get error 400 BadRequest.

All fields are circulated well and everything is stored well if I send an object that is not a subclass.
This is exmp.:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_person")
protected int id_person;
.....

@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="client")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_person")
public class Client extends Person{

@Column(name="address")
protected String address;
....

@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="individual")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_person")
public class Individual extends Client {

@Column(name="personal_number")  
protected String personalNumber;
.....
```

My method inController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/individualPerson", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<Individual>> posttest(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody Individual indiv)
```

Do I need some additional annotations or settings when I send inherited objects?

Also, Hibernate is automatically created all the tables with a primary key that is annotated in these classes.

Comment: With a Http status you can't know what is going wrong. Try something like [REST-CLINET-UI](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) to get your stack trace.

Comment: I try , have you some recommendation for Rest-ClientUI

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSON format, [Jackson library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) by default doesn't need any special annotations. Spring supports it out of the box, so generally you don't need to specify anything else than:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/individualPerson", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
```

Other option is to rely on HTTP content negotiation, which is supported by Spring and don't specify any format in `produces` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You would make two changes if you have `Jackson` library in your path:

1. Mark `@ResponseBody` annotation on the method or on the return type.
2. Add `produces` property set to org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON on `@RequestMapping`